# Oracle APEX: Open Modal Dialog if condition is true

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to open a message box with OK-Button if a PL/SQL Function Body condition is true.

Furthermore, the message box should submit the page it was opened from when being closed.

I already tried several ways, with none of them bein successful.
How can I achieve that?

I use Oracle Apex 5.1.

Comment: Can you just clarify how you want the flow to go?  You want to click a button, run a pl/sql function and open a modal if the result is true, otherwise do nothing?

Comment: @RLOG: Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden page item, e.g. `P1_ITEM` with source null.
Create a button `MY_BUTTON` which submits page.
Create a `computation` for `P1_ITEM` `After Submit` which runs your PL/SQL Function Body and returns 'Y' if the result is true.
Create a `branch` `After Processing` with server-side condition `When Button Pressed = MY_BUTTON` and `Item = Value P1_ITEM, Value 'Y'`.

This will only open the modal if your function evaluates to true (remember to clear the cache on page on redirect so that `P1_ITEM` is no longer = 'Y'.

For your second part, create a `Dynamic Action` of type `Dialog Closed`, `Selection Type` should be the region you click the button in, and `Action Submit Page`.

Edit based on Markus' comment:  If dialog closed doesn't work (probably because the parent page is being submitted initially rather than redirecting), to submit the parent page you can set the button on the modal page to submit with an branch to the parent page.

Comment: I cannot confirm that this works. Upon closing the dialog the parent site won't refresh.

Comment: I did find that the value needs to be written as Y instead of 'Y' in the server-side condition. But no luck with the refresh.

Comment: Yes sorry, i just used the single quotes as a means to show you what to write in there.  Also you don't have to use Y, you could use whatever you want.

Comment: I know, but why not? So, [here](https://i.imgur.com/q1oqeKT.png) is an example of the Debug calls. Page 6 is parent, page 15 is modal. Why doesn't 6 catch 15 when it closes? There is nothing from page 6 after page 15 renders and closes. (Which it does)

Comment: It must be because we are submitting the parent page initially rather than redirecting.  I will have a think about it.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for your opinion. :)

Comment: I found the solution: The OK-Button of the Modal Page needs to be set to submit, and an After Process Redirect to Page 6 (in my case) when button is clicked did the trick.

Comment: Great, that makes sense.  I edited my answer to add your comment.